# Convert event based data to time series

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, time-series, looker

I have inventory events coming into the data warehouse:

| account_id | event_time | item_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 19:20 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 17:20 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02-09 15:40 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-22 09:20 | 1 | 0 |

I want to convert it to time series data by filling in the gaps with whatever was the last value:

| account_id | event_date | item_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-02-03 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-02-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02-07 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02-08 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-02-09 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-10 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-11 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-12 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-13 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-14 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-15 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-16 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-17 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-18 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-19 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-20 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-21 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-22 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-23 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-24 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-25 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-26 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-27 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 0 |

Can we do this without creating a daily snapshot table?
Looking to solve this using SQL than python because we have to build a looker report on top of this.
TechStack is BigQuery+Looker

Comment: Is it possible to use another "calendar" table, which has all of the dates in the range you're looking for, and relating it to this transaction table? That way, you get the full X-axis (a series of dates with no gaps) without creating snapshots. Are you trying to create a table that says "this is how much inventory I had for this product on this day?" If so, then snapshots are probably your best bet, unless you want to do an "accounting" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select account_id, event_date, item_id, quantity
from (
  select *, 
    lead(event_date) over(partition by account_id, item_id order by event_date) next_event_date
  from (
    select account_id, date(split(event_time, ' ')[offset(0)]) event_date, item_id, quantity
    from your_table
  )
), unnest(generate_date_array(event_date, ifnull(next_event_date - 1, '2022-02-28'))) event_date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mikhail-berlyant - this works brilliantly. Can you help me understand how the syntax works for `, unnest(generate_date_array(event_date, ifnull(next_event_date - 1, '2022-02-28'))) event_date` . How does that date get substituted when the original date is not present in the outer most select.