# Converting event-wise table to timeseries

Tags: sql, django, pandas, sqlite

I have an SQLite database (with Django as ORM) with a table of change events (an `Account` is assigned a new `Strategy`). I would like to convert it to a timeseries, to have on each day the `Strategy` the `Account` was following.

My table :

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

As showed, there can be more than 1 change per day. In this case I select the last change of the day, as the desired timeseries output must have only one value per day.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018251/convert-event-based-data-to-time-series) but in SQL, not BigQuery (but I'm not sure I understood the `unnest` part they propose). I have a working solution in Pandas with `reindex` and `fillna`, but I'm sure there is an elegant and simple solution in SQL (maybe even better with Django ORM).

Comment: Your sample data and expected results should include all cases (and edge cases if any) and not just an id and a change for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RECURSIVE Common Table Expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to generate all dates between first and last and then join this generated table with your data to get the needed value for each day:

```
WITH RECURSIVE daterange(d) AS (
  SELECT date(min(created_at)) from events 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT date(d,'1 day') FROM daterange WHERE d<(select max(created_at) from events)
)
SELECT d, account_id, strategy_id
FROM daterange JOIN events
WHERE created_at = (select max(e.created_at) from events e where e.account_id=events.account_id and date(e.created_at) <= d)
GROUP BY account_id, d
ORDER BY account_id, d
```

`date()` function is used to convert a datetime value to a simple date, so you can use it to group your data by date.
`date(d, '1 day')` applies a modifier of +1 calendar day to d.

Here is an example with your data:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  created_at,
  account_id,
  strategy_id
);
```

```
insert into events 
VALUES ('2022-10-07 12:53:53', 4801323843, 7),
('2022-10-07 08:10:07', 4801323843, 5),
('2022-10-07 15:00:45', 4801323843, 8),
('2022-10-10 13:01:16', 4801323843, 6);
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE daterange(d) AS (
  SELECT date(min(created_at)) from events 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT date(d,'1 day') FROM daterange WHERE d<(select max(created_at) from events)
)
SELECT d, account_id, strategy_id
FROM daterange JOIN events
WHERE created_at = (select max(e.created_at) from events e where e.account_id=events.account_id and date(e.created_at) <= d)
GROUP BY account_id, d
ORDER BY account_id, d
```

| d | account_id | strategy_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-07 | 4801323843 | 8 |
| 2022-10-08 | 4801323843 | 8 |
| 2022-10-09 | 4801323843 | 8 |
| 2022-10-10 | 4801323843 | 6 |
| 2022-10-11 | 4801323843 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SJu50PcY)

The query could be slow with many rows. In that case create an index on the created_at column:

```
CREATE INDEX events_created_idx ON events(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

My final version is the version proposed by @Andrea B., with just a slight improve in performance, merging only the rows that we need in the join, and therefore discarding the `where` clause.
I also converted the `null` to `date('now')`
Here is the final version I used :

```
with recursive daterange(day) as 
  (
    select min(date(created_at)) from events
    union all select date(day, '1 day') from daterange
    where day < date('now')
  ),
  events as (
    select account_id, strategy_id, created_at as start_date, 
    case lead(created_at) over(partition by account_id order by created_at) is null
      when True then datetime('now')
      else lead(created_at) over(partition by account_id  order by created_at) 
    end as end_date
    from events
  )
  select * from daterange
  join events on events.start_date<daterange.day and daterange.day<events.end_date
  order by events.account_id
```

Hope this helps !